Virtualbox Installation Problems on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I am trying to install Virtual box but it keeps giving me problems, the manager window will open fine but it keeps giving me this message in the terminal.
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

I reinstalled it and then I had these errors in installation.

× virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-09-19 11:25:15 +03; 1min>
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 34263 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=>
        CPU: 45ms

Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: Starting virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox>
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use>
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:    ...fail!
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, c>
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit->
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: Failed to start virtualbox.service - LSB: Vir>
lines 1-14/14 (END)...skipping...
× virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-09-19 11:25:15 +03; 1min 59s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 34263 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 45ms

Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: Starting virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi virtualbox[34263]:    ...fail!
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 19 11:25:15 Moudi systemd[1]: Failed to start virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
~

I tried all the suggestions in that old post except disabling secure boot because it doesn't seem like a good idea. I got this:
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xeu virtualbox.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
× virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-09-21 12:57:26 +03; 20ms ago
   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 66621 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 44ms

Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi systemd[1]: Starting virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi virtualbox[66621]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi virtualbox[66621]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi virtualbox[66621]:    ...fail!
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 21 12:57:26 Moudi systemd[1]: Failed to start virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
moudi@Moudi:~$ dmesg
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted


Reads like a VirtualBox issue not Ubuntu. Have you asked on their support?

I am a newbie so I am not sure if I am the issue. There was a problem with signing the files in the first installation, so I made a key and rebooted, but VBox  did not do anything?

This question is similar to: VirtualBox Error : The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I added the edit to the post thanks

Disable secure boot or go through the 'mokutil' steps to sign the driver. You have to do one or the other, or vb can't run.

Thanks I ended up disabling secure boot, since the signing process went terribly
